# Kraken JS Permission Denied

Tags: kraken.js

When I "yo kraken", the following comes up.  Any idea?  I have tried to reinstalling update-notifier as well.

Error: EACCES, permission denied '/home/X/.config/configstore/update-notifier-yo.yml'
You don't have access to this file.

```
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
at Object.create.all.set (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:56:8)
at Object.Configstore (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:19:11)
at new UpdateNotifier (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/lib/update-notifier.js:34:17)
at module.exports (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/update-notifier/lib/update-notifier.js:140:23)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:128:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permissions on your `~/.config/` and `~/.config/configstore/`. You've probably run things with sudo that didn't need it, so you've got root-owned files in your personal or service's home directory. That confuses everything when you go follow up with non-sudoed commands. You'll want to `sudo chown` them back to the right user.

In general, know whether a command is going to write to system / shared locations (`/usr/local`) or personal ones (inside `~`). Only use sudo when you need to.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with another file in krakenjs.

```
npm cache clean
```

Fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

It might be caused by permission denied

try to run:

```
sudo yo kraken
```

*P.S. Be sure you have permissions to write on that directory*